# select query with array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I save with the first query any values into an array `$ownco`. With the second query I try to get all rows of the table posts where the `id` have the same values as in the array `$ownco`.

two errors:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in
>   'where clause'
>
> :  Array to string conversion in line 34

```
$hostname='localhost';
            $user='root';
            $password='';
            $useron = $_COOKIE['username'];
                    try {
                            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=searchfood",$user,$password);

                            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                             $sql = "SELECT id_post 
    FROM comments 
    WHERE username = '$useron'
    ORDER BY id DESC"; // oder (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la) versuchen
      if ($own = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
          // then after fetchColumn
         $ownco = $own->fetchAll();      
       }                        
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                    }  


                    try {
                            $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=searchfood",$user,$password);

                            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                             $sql = "SELECT id, autorid, autor, date, longitude, latitude, title, text, town, time 
    FROM posts 
    WHERE id in (" . implode(",",$ownco) . ") // line 34
    ORDER BY id DESC"; // oder (longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la) versuchen
      if ($resco = $dbh->query($sql)) {// need to add this line in your code
          // then after fetchColumn
         $resultcom = $resco->fetchAll();        
       }                        
                    }
                    catch(PDOException $e)
                    {
                            echo $e->getMessage();
                    }
```

Comment: can you share `var_dump( implode(",",$ownco) )` result?

Comment: no need for the 2 queries this could be done in one with a join

Comment: You can do a single subquery :`SELECT id, .... FROM posts WHERE id in (SELECT id_post FROM comments WHERE.... ) ORDER BY id DESC`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the fetch style. Currently you are using the default "FETCH_BOTH" which results in something like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => pear
            [0] => pear
```

If you change the fetchAll to only fetch the column it should work as expected.

```
$ownco = $own->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

Results:

```
Array
(
    [0] = 1,
    [1] = 3,
```

etc.